# Width of Table Cell with Rotated Text -- HTML

Tags: html, css

I have some vertically-oriented text in a table cell.  However, the cell seems to be taking the width of the text as if it were horizontally oriented and I want it to take on the width of the vertically oriented text.

What I have: http://jsfiddle.net/a20rp5y3/

What I'm going for: http://jsfiddle.net/p4EPd/ (the "Overall Satisfaction" column specifically)

It seems that `position: absolute` is the key here, but I don't know how to implement it in my example.

Thoughts?

Comment: Always post your code in your question please.

Comment: Posting the full code seemed obtuse since it would have been many lines.

Comment: Many lines or not, code goes in your question first. Then you can optionally supplement it with an example on another site.

Answer (score 1):

That 2nd sample is "cheating" you to think it works. Replace the contents of the to lower TDs (below the satisfaction cell) to something short like '|' and you'll see it doesn't really work.

The reason is that CSS transforms don't affect bounding box calculations. You need to set your sizing properties "by hand".

Comment: But what is this then? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/writing-mode. This is the first time reading about this property but it almost seems like it's trying to solve his problem, but I can't get it to work.

Comment: @Amit: How do you set the "sizing properties by hand"?

Comment: It's experimental technology, that doesn't exists in some browsers, and doesn't "really" work in others

Comment: Set the content to overflow hidden, and set a css width attribute

Comment: I tried that on the `<div>` that is being rotated.  It didn't give the effect I want because the `<td>` that contains it is still too wide.  Any other ideas?

Comment: did you set the overflow to hidden? set another fiddle with this

Comment: This is close (http://jsfiddle.net/a20rp5y3/4/), but it's not quite there.  Setting `overflow: hidden" actually hides some of the text that needs to be displayed.

Comment: I don't see what gets hidden, but you got the general idea. As my answer states, the browser won't help you here, you need to do everything by hand.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82136/discussion-between-gtilflm-and-amit).